# Recursive java script function - out of control

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

The code below works. The code calls an API to get historical trades (100 trades each time pér pull). Because there is an limit - how many and how often im allowed to call the API - the structure is like recursive.

***The flow is like this:***

1. Get the current MAX tradeId - which is stored in the DB.
2. Now make a new PULL with startIndex = MaxId and a length of 100 (to pull 100 new trades).
3. FIRST when the callback function is called the main code continues and 100 new trades are pulled... ect. ect.

So...

***The code SHOULD behave like - Psydo-code***

```
var maxId = GetMaxIdFromDB();

Pull(maxId, 100, callback);

function callback(){

... do different stuff..
maxId += 100;

Pull(maxId, 100, callback);

}
```

The strange thing and my question is: How can the API function "**getProductTrades** " be called more than one time - where my **cursor** variable contains the **SAME value** - when it is incremented with 100 (or the number of valid data elements each time).

***I'm talking/ref. especially to the following lines:***

```
wl.debug("getProductTrades - cursor: " + cursor + " Limit: " + limit);
                publicClient.getProductTrades({'after': cursor, 'limit': limit}, callback);
```

The **insertQuery.InsertMatchMsgArrayToDB(allData);** method calls another DB method which returns a promise.

You can see a screenshot of the issue here:
http://screencast.com/t/DH8rz3UxnyZ

***The real code is here:***

```
pullTradesBetween: function (minTradeId, maxTradeId) {

            var wl = new WinLog();
            var tradeCounter = 0;

            try {
                var WebSocketEmit = new WSemitter();
                var startTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
                var executeTradePullAgain = null;

                wl.debug("REST API START: " + startTime);

                var cursor;
                var incrementedCursorWith = 0;

                if ((maxTradeId - minTradeId) < 100) {
                    cursor = maxTradeId + 1;
                }
                else
                    cursor = minTradeId + 100;

                var callback = function (err, response, data) {

                    if (executeTradePullAgain !== null)
                        clearTimeout(executeTradePullAgain);

                    if (err)
                        wl.info("Err: " + err);

                    var validData = [];
                    incrementedCursorWith = 0;

                    if (response == null)
                        wl.info("RESPONSE ER NULL");

                    if (data !== null) {
                        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            var obj = data[i];

                            var tradeId = parseInt(obj.trade_id);

                            if (obj !== null && (minTradeId <= tradeId && tradeId <= maxTradeId)) {
                                validData.push(data[i]);
                            }
                        }

                        if (validData.length == 0) {
                            wl.debug("Contains 0 elements!");
                        }
                        else {
                            cursor = cursor + validData.length;
                            incrementedCursorWith = validData.length;
                            insertDataToDB(validData);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        wl.debug("DATA IS NULL!");

                    wl.debug("cursor: " + cursor + " maxTradeId: " + maxTradeId);

                    var diffToMax = maxTradeId - (cursor - incrementedCursorWith);

                    if (diffToMax >= 100)
                        pullTrades(cursor, 100); // 100 is default
                    else if (diffToMax >= 0)
                        pullTrades(maxTradeId + 1, diffToMax + 1); // X = Only the last trades in the given series of trades
                    else {
                        wl.info("REST API START: " + startTime + " REST API DONE: " + new Date().toLocaleString());

                        WebSocketEmit.syncHistoricalDataDone();
                    }
                };

                function pullTrades(cursor, limit) {

                    tradeCounter += limit;

                    if(tradeCounter % 10000 == 0){
                        wl.info('Downloaded: ' + tradeCounter + ' trades via REST API (Total: ' + cursor + ')');
                    }

                    pullTradesAgainIfServerDoesNotRespond(cursor, limit);

                    wl.debug("getProductTrades - cursor: " + cursor + " Limit: " + limit);
                    publicClient.getProductTrades({'after': cursor, 'limit': limit}, callback);
                }

                function pullTradesAgainIfServerDoesNotRespond(cursor, limit) {

                    executeTradePullAgain = setTimeout(function () {
                        wl.debug('pullTradesAgainIfServerDoesNotRespond called!');
                        pullTrades(cursor, limit);
                    }, 30000);
                }

                // SAVE DATA IN DB!
                function insertDataToDB(allData) {
                    insertQuery.InsertMatchMsgArrayToDB(allData);
                }

                wl.debug("pull trades: " + cursor);
                pullTrades(cursor, 100);
            }
            catch(err){
                wl.info('pullTradesBetween: ' + err);
            } }};
```

Comment: Are you sure `publicClient.getProductTrades()` calls the callback only once every time?

Comment: The API DOC doesn't say any thing about that - but i would find it rather strange - if the API return 5 x 20 objects - when i request 100 ...haha...

I just added some more logging to test ... and i look like it only and always return, calls, returns, calls... look here: http://screencast.com/t/YkGvgfBcOMqb

Comment: This might be a naive point of view here... but what excactly does guarantee `maxId - minId` equals `100`? Trade entries could have been deleted, this does not really look like a safe thing to assume

Comment: i pull/request 100 - the API will allway return the given number of items... until no more item exist to pull... the data contains a seq.-no which the client use to ensure - that the trades comes in the correct order - and nothing is missing... the client needs to implement error-handling for this... like i did.. look a "validData" ...

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you get no data out of `getProductionTrades`.
If the data returned is null, you will never reach the lines

```
cursor = cursor + validData.length;
incrementedCursorWith = validData.length;
```

but you still call

```
pullTrades(cursor, 100);
```

at the end. I don't know if it's intended or an actual error so i leave the solution (should be trivial now) up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I try to simplify your code

```
pullTradesBetween: function (minTradeId, maxTradeId) {
    var WebSocketEmit = new WSemitter(); // try-catch ?
    var curr = (maxTradeId - minTradeId < 100) ? maxTradeId + 1 : minTradeId + 100;

    // function always return data or infinite error-loop
    function getProductTrades (after, limit, callback) {
        // try-catch ?
        publicClient.getProductTrades ({after, limit}, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return getTrades(after, limit, callback);
            }

            callback(null, data);
        });
    }

    function onDataReady (err, data) {
        if (err)
            throw new Error('Impossible!');

        if (!data || !(data instanceof Array))  
            return ... smth on empty data ...

        var validData = data.filter(function(obj) {
            return obj && 
                minTradeId <= parseInt(obj.trade_id) &&
                parseInt(obj.trade_id) <= maxTradeId;
        }).reverse();

        if (validData.length == 0)
            return ... smth on empty data ...

        insertDataToDB(validData);

        curr += validData.length; // maybe +-1 

        var remaining = maxTradeId - curr;
        if (remainig == 0) {
            console.log('Done');
            // try-catch ?
            WebSocketEmit.syncHistoricalDataDone();
        }

        return (remaining >= 100) ? 
            getProductTrades(curr, 100, onDataReady) : 
            getProductTrades(maxTradeId + 1, remaining + 1, onDataReady); // ??
    }

    getProductTrades(curr, 100, onDataReady);
}
```